# Parsing a request body containing a quoted string as JSON in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have an application which exposes an endpoint accepting `PUT` requests as a JSON-formatted string, e.g.:

```
PUT /my/endpoint
"some string"
```

My endpoint method signature is something like:

```java
@RequestMapping(
        path = "/my/endpoint",
        consumes = "application/vnd.mycompany.myservice-v1.hal+json"
)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> myEndpoint(
        @RequestBody final String myString
) {
    ...
}
```

Using Spring Boot 1 (1.5.22.RELEASE), the value of `myString` given the `PUT` example above would be the literal text `some string`, but under Spring Boot 2 (2.3.6.RELEASE), it's now the literal text `"some string"` - i.e. it seems that the input isn't strictly being parsed as JSON because the quotes are not removed.

I believe that quoted strings are valid JSON (and that unquoted strings are not), just as an object (in `{` and `}`) and a list (in `[` and `]`) would be.

I've taken out some extraneous detail that I don't think matters for the problem at hand (e.g. we're using `CompletableFuture` as a return value, I've got a `@PathVariable` in there as well and there's some annotation-driven validation going on), but I've left in that we're using a custom media-type in case that has something to do with it.

Any ideas how I can convince Spring Boot 2 to treat my request body as JSON properly? Unfortunately, I can't redefine the API because we already have live customers using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be the best option but if nothing else helps at start. Instead of `String` let Spring handle `RequestBody` as an `Object`. So like:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> myEndpoint(@RequestBody final Object myString)
```

When using `String` Spring might not even use Jackson for parsing but handle the body as a `String` that should have all the characters in the body even content type is set to JSON.

If you do the following:

```
String myString2 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(myString, String.class);
```

you can see it resulting into `myString2` having not those surrounding double quotes.

For `Object` Spring seems to handle it differently. It makes it to a `String` but seems to consider it as a JSON value (and as a `String` value because having surrounding double quotes) it should not have surrounding double quotes.

If you use `Object` and then log `myString.getClass()` you will see it is actually a `java.lang.String`

Comment: Genius, this is exactly what I was looking for - need to implement a few safe-guards around it, but it does convince Spring to treat the incoming request properly. Not sure I would have thought of that alone.

Answer (score 0):

You Can create the request object

```
public class MyObject{
private String myStr;

}
```

Use the MyObject class as RequestBody object with `mediaType="application/json"`

In your controller

```
@RequestMapping(
        value= "/my/endpoint", method= RequestMethod.PUT
)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> myEndpoint(
        @RequestBody final MyObject myObj
)
```